# Pass a Parameter in SSRS while removing Dashes

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am passing a unique ID as parameter in SSRS report. In the source table, unique id does not contain dashed. However, the user may insert Unique ID including dashes "-" and in some cases without dashes. Is there a way that we could remove dashes from the parameter.

For example, unique id 3120-20268-8 is stored in table as 3120202688. How I could retrieve if user pass multiple values with or without dashes in the SSRS Report.

When is used below query, it gives record against single value only. However, gives error when more than one values are provided.

select * from Table
where Unique_ID in (REPLACE(@Unique_ID,'-',''))

For more than 1 values, it gives errors mentioned below:

### The replace function requires 3 argument(s).

Query execution failed for dataset 'ATL_List'.

Thanks

Comment: So your parameter is a multi-value parameter? that is significantly different but can still be done.

Comment: Yes Chris, it is multi-Value parameter. Can you guide me how to handle this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the simplest mechanisms for this is to create an expression based parameter to hold the sanitised input. This parameter would be hidden so the user is not aware of it, but the rest of the usage of the parameter is the same.

> **NOTE:** You could do something similar with a *query based* default value, but this case is easier to do via a simple expression

## Single Value Parameter

Create a new parameter:

- set it to hidden
  [image: Hidden Parameter]
- Set the default value expression:

  ```
     =Str(Parameters!inputID.Value).Replace("-","")
  ```

  [image: Default value for parameter]

## Multi-Value Parameter

This is only slightly trickier, in the expression we can join the selected values together into a CSV string, then process that value and then split it back:

- Set the parameter to multi-value, but still hidden:
  [image: Hidden multivalue parameter]
- Set the default value expression:

  ```
     =Join(Parameters!inputID.Value,",").Replace("-","").Split(",")
  ```

Without going to detailed, if we made the sanitised parameter *temporarily* visible, **just to demonstrate the conversion**, it should look like this:

[image: Raw and sanitised input]

### The parameter MUST be hidden!

> **NOTE:** *DO NOT* make your sanitised parameter visible as in the above screenshot in your deployed report! Doing so will mean that it will not pickup changes made to the input value after it has rendered the first time.
> *remember that we have exploited the **default** value, we haven't arbitrarily defined en expression to always execute.*

The output when the parameter is *hidden* is calculated when the report is rendered, it's just harder to visualise the behavior in this static post:

[image: hidden sanitised parameter]

In your DataSet query you would just use the sanitised parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Unique_ID IN (@sanitisedMultiValue)
```

Comment: There maybe a problem when the user enters some values at Input ID, The Sanitised Input is updated with the default value, and after that the user changes the input before pressing the view report button

Comment: To help you improve your answer: make the second parameter single value with the total string. Use a third multivalue parameter to make the transformation. Seems in that way it always refreshes the parameter

Comment: @niktrs I see what you mean, except that when the parameter is hidden it is not resolved until it is needed. If the parameter is visible then it will only render the first time, I just wanted to show something on the screen, I'll change the example

Comment: You are right, it always works when hidden. Nice to know!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the replace function in your report to format the parameter value after it has been entered, something like the below

replace(Fields!Paramater.Value,"-","")=FieldinYourTable

Comment: this doesn't help for multi-value parameters.

Comment: Yes I am aware, the post did not originally say it was multi-value parameter, so my answer was based on the origional information. Your answer is the rightway to go about this for the question as it now is

Comment: I know, I only added that comment for posterity for future readers, after the post was changed... multi-value is a significant element, glad it was updated,

Comment: I should have mentioned this, just change the Advanced refresh options to _Always Refresh_ then there's no issue. Theres no reason another hidden parameter would refresh better than 1.